# how to get the post attachement image in full size?

Tags: theme-development, loop, themes

Hi i am using the normal loop to get the post content. Objective is to show images or videos in the blog.

I tried `the_content()` for the loop but am getting the thumbnail image i belive, What i want is the original image should be there.

Here is the code

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :
              while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                   the_content();//by this am getting the medium sized images from the post content as it is uploaded through add media
              endwhile;
              endif;
        ?>
```

Now i want to show full size of the image for each post. How to do it.

can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say that your image is "uploaded through add media", you need to select the full sized image when you attach it to the post, not when you try to display it. You should even see in the markup that a smaller size has been chosen (by you).

Look over on the right side in the sidebar toward the bottom. You should see a dropdown that will let you choose "size".

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't noticed for the past one month. This will be appropriate for me by this using `the_content()` alone i can able to show video as well as images without any conditional statement in my loop. +1 @s_ha_dum

Comment: If you have anything to say. Just say:)

Comment: Hi i have one doubt, Can i make pagination from this loop or should i use wp_query object then make pagination. Which is possible if you let me know this i'll ask a separate question based on that. Thanks @s_ha_dum

Comment: You can paginate any Loop, but how you do it depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

This outputs the Post Thumbnail/Featured Image in full size:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail())
    {
      $full = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' );
      echo '<img src="' . $full[0] . '">';
    } else {
      echo 'No post thumbnail.';
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code i'll try to use whenever i need this knowledge. +1 @luke